# git: create new remote repo with http backend?

Tags: http, git

I set up access to git over apache2 and the git-http-backend as described in http://www.tikalk.com/alm/setup-git-gitweb-git-http-backend-smart-http-ubuntu-1204 . I can pull from the test repository which already exists remotely.

I have however hard time pushing a repository I created locally to the remote server such that a new repository is set up there. I am a beginner with git, so I might be missing something obvious.

I create a test repository like this:

```
mkdir test2
cd test2
git init .
echo blah > foo.txt
git add .
git commit -m'initial commit'
```

I try this:

```
git push http://myserver/git/test2.git
fatal: repository 'http://myserver/git/test2.git/' not found
```

or this:

```
git push --set-upstream http://myserver/git/test2.git master
fatal: repository 'http://myserver/git/test2.git/' not found
```

Any hint?

Comment: Git 'push' will not create new repository on the remote. You must initialize it by `git init --bare`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382565/how-to-git-push-to-remote-if-remote-does-not-exist-at-all)

Comment: In another words, there is way (can be something else than `push`) to get the repo to the remote without `ssh`'ing there? I am migrating away from `bzr` and this is something it trivially supports.

Comment: Did you mean git command like `bzr init-repo`?

Comment: I mean something like `bzr push https+webdav://myserver/bzr/new-repo` which pushes the branch to the `new-repo` which perhaps does not exist yet. Or to create a remote repo, I was able to do `bzr init https+webdav://myserver/bzr/new-repo` (running that command locally, creating the repo remotely).

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a remote Git repository over the Git protocol.

You can use Gitorious, or a similar web interface, where you can create a remote repository. Git Web was installed in your tutorial but I assume it can't create a repository since you haven't found that feature.